# Equality of $\limsup$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $q>1$ be a real number and $f$ and $g$ be two non-decreasing functions defined on $\mathbb R^+$ such that $g(a)=f(a)$ for every $a\in\mathbb Q^+$. Can one assert that $\limsup_{r\to+\infty}\frac{g(r)}{q^r}=\limsup_{r\to+\infty}\frac{f(r)}{q^r}$? Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon >0$. There exists $M$ such that $\lim \sup \frac {f(r)} {q^{r}} +\epsilon > \frac {f(r)} {q^{r}}$ whenever $r >M$. Now let $r>M$ and choose a rational number $s$ such that $r<s<r+\epsilon$ and $q^{s-r} <1+\epsilon$. Then $\frac {g(r)} {q^{r}}\leq \frac {g(s)} {q^{s}} q^{s-r}=\frac {f(s)} {q^{s}} q^{s-r}$. Hence $\frac {g(r)} {q^{r}}\leq (1+\epsilon) (\lim \sup \frac {f(r)} {q^{r}} +\epsilon)$. It follows that $\lim \sup \frac {g(r)} {q^{r}}$ does not exceed $(1+\epsilon)$ times $\lim \sup \frac {f(r)} {q^{r}}+\epsilon$ and $\epsilon $ is arbitrary. The reverse inequality is similar.

Comment: Thanks. I understood what you did.